# How can I attach a BTS7960 43A motor controller circuit and control it from a keyboard wirelessly through the Raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, gpio, python, rpi.gpio

I need to attach a BTS7960 43A motor control circuit to the Raspberry Pi. Could anyone please tell me the connections and provide me with a link to a python code to drive motors forward and reverse through a wireless keyboard. 
I am a mechanical engr. and not having much knowledge about this, but I grasp the basics.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the wireless keyboard working with the Pi? If so, it's just a matter of connecting and getting the code.

Here's are a couple links that should help connecting the BTS7960
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1124139
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/398556/how-to-control-a-motor-driver-bts7960-without-pwm

and have you seen these projects?
https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/?interests[]=robotics

The robot buggy project has some good explanation of one code option

Comment: Thanks very much. I didn't expect help so soon, glad this site is so active. Yes I have a wireless keyboard and mouse. I use it with the Pi. I'm looking into the links shared now.

Comment: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/JAKCOM-CC2-Smart-Compact-Camera-Hot-Sale-in-Mini-Camera-as-360-Panorama-Sport-Support-TF/32863470090.html

Comment: I want to attach this camera to my Pi board and stream the video via the Pi over ssh on to my Android phone(Redmi 4)   I have setup Terminus and ssh ed into the Pi from my Phone and can access it and run programs wirelessly.,,,,, just any way the video can be streamed?   And the camera has a 3 in one cable ( USB, mini usb and a TV video input. Do I need to purchase a TV in adapter for my Pi to plug this cam into my Pi?  I had been looking these links for the past month. I waited for the new jumper wires to arrive.  I'll try and test it . But if anyone can help with the camera itd be perfect

Comment: I don’t know about that camera, I use the Raspberry Pi camera module v2. I haven’t streamed the camera over ssh but I do ssh -X to display apps from the pi on my laptop. Maybe a VNC app on your phone could do it. You should ask your question about the camera as a separate question to get more people to see it. Also mark this question as answered once you’ve gotten your answer.